# SQL Select most recent record for each group

Tags: sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the most recent record for each user in my table:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Orders 
WHERE State = Active 
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY Orders.DateTimePlanned DESC`
```

But this results me in the oldest record of each user, how can I get the most recent one!? Changing the `DESC` to `ASC` doesn't work!

Please let me know!

Comment: tag your dbms name and if support window function try to use row_number()

Comment: perhaps add the query here so the community can use that and show you the updated query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not valid standard SQL. Presumably, you are running MySQL with sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled.

You need to *filter* the dataset rather than aggregate it. One option uses a subquery:

```
select *  
from orders o
where state = 'Active' and datetimeplanned = (
    select max(o1.datetimeplanned)
    from orders o1
    where o1.userid = o.userid and o1.state = 'Active'
)
```

You can also use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
select *  
from (
    select o.*, rank() over(partition by userid order by datetimeplanned desc) rn
    from orders o
    where state = 'Active'
) o
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a sub query

Have a look at this script, it uses a subquery and takes the last row and reduces it using the value of the previous row to project data growth of a database

declare @backupType char(1)
, @DatabaseName sysname

```
set @DatabaseName   = db_name() --> Name of current database, null for all databaseson server
set @backupType     ='D'        /* valid options are:
                                D = Database 
                                I = Database Differential 
                                L = Log 
                                F = File or Filegroup 
                                G = File Differential 
                                P = Partial 
                                Q = Partial Differential
                                */



select  backup_start_date
      , backup_finish_date
      , DurationSec
      , database_name,backup_size
      , PreviouseBackupSize
      , backup_size-PreviouseBackupSize as growth
      ,KbSec= format(KbSec,'N2')
FROM (
select backup_start_date 
     , backup_finish_date
     , datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date) as DurationSec 
     , b.database_name
     , b.backup_size/1024./1024. as backup_size

     ,case when datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date) >0 
        then ( b.backup_size/1024.)/datediff(second,backup_start_date,b.backup_finish_date)
        else 0 end as KbSec
--   , b.compressed_backup_size
     , (      
        select top (1) p.backup_size/1024./1024. 
          from msdb.dbo.backupset p 
         where p.database_name = b.database_name
           and p.database_backup_lsn< b.database_backup_lsn
            and type=@backupType
         order by p.database_backup_lsn desc
        ) as PreviouseBackupSize
from msdb.dbo.backupset as b
where @DatabaseName IS NULL OR database_name =@DatabaseName
and type=@backupType
)as A
order by backup_start_date desc
```